# Pushing an object with unique_ptr into vector in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, smart-pointers, move-semantics

I have a simple class structure modelling a discrete simulation, with a vector of States, which each contain a number of Transitions, held as a vector of smart pointers. I've used smart pointers to hold the transitions as in my full application I need polymorphism.

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

class Transition {
    public:
        Transition() {}
};


class State {
    public:
        State(int num) : num(num), transitions() {}
        void add_transition(std::unique_ptr<Transition> trans) {
            transitions.push_back(std::move(trans));
        }

    private:
        int num;
        std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Transition>> transitions;
};


int main() {
    std::vector<State> states;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        State nstate = State(i);
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            nstate.add_transition(std::move(std::unique_ptr<Transition>(new Transition())));
        }
        // This line causes compiler errors
        states.push_back(nstate);
    }
}
```

I get compiler errors when adding the new state object to the vector:

```
Error: use of deleted function ‘std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>&) [with _Tp = Transition; _Dp = std::default_delete<Transition>]’
 { ::new(static_cast<void*>(__p)) _T1(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }
```

I imagine this is due to vector making a copy of the State object which is also trying to make a copy of the vector of `unique_ptrs` which isn't allowed. I've seen that `emplace_back` doesn't make copies like `push_back` does but I still get the same error.

Adding the State object directly into the vector works, but I'd prefer to avoid this workaround as in my actual code I do more work with the State object rather than just adding transitions and don't want to keep accessing the vector.

```
int main() {
    std::vector<State> states;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        states.push_back(State(i));
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            states[i].add_transition(std::move(std::unique_ptr<Transition>(new Transition())));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Add a move constructor, you can default it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`State` is not copyable, but only moveable; But for `states.push_back(nstate);`, `nstate` is an lvalue (as a named variable), which can't be moved from. Then a copy is tried to perform but it's not allowed.

To solve it you could use `std::move` (to turn it to an rvalue):

```
states.push_back(std::move(nstate));
```

[LIVE](http://rextester.com/MWA18395)

---

Note that after the move operation, the data member of `nstate` (including the vector and its content) will be moved too.

Comment: This works without the need for creating a default move constructor

Comment: @StuartLacy It's implicitly generated for `State`.

Comment: It doesn't fully solve the problem. At the end of the `push_back` then `nstate` will be empty (hold `nullptr`) and leave the op only able to access the state by de-referencing the array which they hoped not to do. Take a pointer `State* pnstate=nstate.get()` before the `push_back` if that's the plan.

Comment: @Persixty If OP has to access `nstate` after the `push_back()` statement, yes it's problematic. But he didn't show that usage in the code sample, so I supposed that `push_back()` is the last statement in the for loop.

Comment: @songyuanyao It's what I read "I do more work with the State object rather than just adding transitions and don't want to keep accessing the vector." in the OP as meaning. He needs to either dynamically allocate State or access the vector one more time (possibly as a reference) after your move. We both know the salient pointer. After the move `nstate` is empty.

Comment: @Persixty That's because in his 2nd code sample, he can't address the unnamed object `State(i)`, then has to access it via the vector. For the 1st case we have a named variable `nstate`; and I can't see why we can't put the `push_back` as the last statement.

Comment: Exactly, I put the `push_back` as the last statement in the loop so I can do whatever I need to with `nstate` beforehand. Maybe I wasn't clear enough in my question

Comment: @songyuanyao Depends what that work is. If it's create other pointers/references to that object in other objects he'll come unstuck by the same fact. I still think it's worth pointing out that the state has (well, erm) moved after the `std::move`...

Comment: @StuartLacy If you only then access state in the vector by look by index or `num` you're fine. But labor intensive O(n) accesses like "find state `num`" usually fall down very early in any graph intensive implementation (which this looks like). The design usually turns to direct pointers/references at some point in which case your 'move' may let you down...

Comment: Thanks for the advice. There are no other references to the State objects, and they are only accessed from the vector by index so the current `move` solution is fine. I'll bear that in mind if the design becomes more complex

Comment: @Persixty Fair enough. I added it.

Answer (score 3):

You need to make an ownership decision.

The owner (or owners) of a `new` allocated object are responsible for ensuring it is 'delete'ed at the end of its lifecycle.

If the `vector<>` owns the object then `std::move()` the `std::unique_ptr<>` into the `vector` and continue to access the object through a 'raw' pointer but will be invalidated if the `vector` is destructed or the `std::unique_ptr` is erased/reset.

If the `vector<>` doesn't own the object than declare it `vector<State*>` and recognise it will be invalidated when the `std::unique_ptr` is destructed (unless you intervene).

If there's a complex relationship consider `std::shared_ptr<>` which will allow multiple objects to share ownership but make sure that circular referencing can't take place.

Beyond that you're into more complex ownership models and possible 'garbage collection'.

A superficial examination suggests a 'State' probably owns its `Transition`s because on the whole they make sense while the state exists and stop making sense when it doesn't. So continue with the `vector<std::unique_ptr<> >` and access `State` and/or `Transition` as a pointer.

If that doesn't work in your case, you probably need a 'FiniteState' context object that owns all the states and all the transitions and takes care to remove all the states and all the associated transitions from and to when a state is destroyed.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> // This line causes compiler errors
> states.push_back(nstate);
> ```

The `nstate` object is an instance of the `State` class. The `State` class contains two data members: an `int` (which is copyable), and a `vector` of `unique_ptr`s, that is *movable but not copyable* (since `unique_ptr` is movable but not copyable). As a result of that, the whole `State` class is movable but not copyable. So, you must `std::move` the `nstate` object into the `states` vector:

```
states.push_back(std::move(nstate));
```

If you want *copy* semantics, you should use a vector of `shared_ptr`s (that are *reference counted* smart pointers, and are *both* copyable and movable).

---

I would do also a few modifications to your `State` class code:

> ```
> class State {
>     public:
>         State(int num) : num(num), transitions() {}
> ```

Here, you should mark the constructor `explicit`, to avoid *implicit* conversions from `int`. Moreover, the `std::vector` data member is automatically initialized, no need to use `transitions()` here.

Moreover, considering this line of code:

> ```
> states[i].add_transition(std::move(std::unique_ptr<Transition>(new Transition())));
> ```

you should to use `std::make_unique` (introduced in C++14) instead of constructing a `std::unique_ptr` with the raw pointer returned by an explicit call to `new`.

Comment: Annoyingly I'm stuck with C++11, but will bear that in mind

Answer (score 2):

You should avoid using `push_back` and use `emplace_back` to create items inplace instead.

```
constexpr ::std::int32_t const states_count{10};
constexpr ::std::int32_t const transitions_per_state_count{2};
::std::vector< State > states;
states.reserve(states_count);
for(::std::int32_t state_index{}; states_count != state_index; ++state_index)
{
    states.emplace_back(state_index); // new state is added without copying or moving anything
    auto & nstate{states.back()};
    for(::std::int32_t transition_index{}; transitions_per_state_count != transition_index; ++transition_index)
    {
        nstate.add_transition(::std::unique_ptr< Transition >{new Transition{}});
    }
}
```

Comment: Since C++17: `auto& nstate = states.emplace_back(state_index);`

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement a move constructor for your `State` and call `std::move` to move the object

```
class State {
public:
    // default if you just want it to move the members one by one
    State(State&& s) = default;
};

states.push_back(std::move(nstate));
```

Comment: The code runs without specifying the move constructor, is the declaration of it as default just to be explicit or does it serve some other role?

Comment: @StuartLacy Under some conditions, the move constructor will be implicitly created by the compiler. Under some other conditions, it won't, then an explicitly defaulted one is required. Writing it down either way is just good practice and serves as documentation

Answer (score 1):

You are passing `std::unique_ptr<Transition>` to function by value, which should create a local copy in `void add_transition(std::unique_ptr<Transition> trans)`.

If you will pass value by reference `std::unique_ptr<Transition>& trans`, you wouldn't need any `std::move` outside `add_transition` function.

Also you may want to use `std::make_unique<Transition>()` instead of `std::uniqye_ptr<Transition>(new Transition())`.

Encapsulation of `new` keyword makes your code clearer and decreeses probability of creating memory leak.